# Compiler warnings about methods not found or not declared

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, compiler-warnings

I have started using (ARC) with iOS 5, but I have a problem which appears often.

First case:

```
[[cell viewWithTag:999] setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
```

this line causes the problem:

> Receiver type 'UIView' for instance message does not declare a method with selector 'setTextColor:'.

Second case:

```
[delegate setForTheFirstTime:TRUE];
```

this line cause the problem:

> No known instance method for selector 'setForTheFirstTime:'.

I have a lot of problems like these when I use a delegate.

To fix these two problems, must I use a method like `performSelector:`?

Comment: Uhm, what has all of this to do with ARC?

Comment: Neither of these look like ARC-related issues. Are you sure the warnings have only started when using ARC? Maybe you've switched to LLVM for the first time?

Comment: Have you tried casting the `viewWithTag:` call to `UILabel*` or whatever it is? Is the `delegate` typed as `id <ProtocolHere>`? Looks like you're just getting warnings related to sending messages to objects that may or may not implement an appropriate method.

Comment: @JustSid, the behavior is different without ARC. Sans ARC, this is a warning, not an error. For people who ignored warnings (yuck), this is a change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to declare 'delegate' as the correct type, which will require you to import that type's header. The compiler needs to know that your delegate object understands 'setForTheFirstTime:' and the compiler needs the declaration for that method.

In the first case with viewWithTag:, you need to cast the result to the correct class so the compiler can know about that 'setTextColor:' method.

Assuming this view is a UILabel:

`[(UILabel*)[cell viewWithTag:999] setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];`

Answer (score 0):

viewWithTag method is returning an UIView object. So when you call the setTextColor method, the receiver is a UIView and there is no setTextColor method for a UIView. You have to cast your object to the correct class. Here you want a UILabel.